# Best practice to connect from test iphone to local server

Tags: ios

Is there a standard way to build iOS apps in xcode such that, when running on a test iphone, the app can connect to a dev server running on my laptop?

For context, I'm making GET/POST requests to a remote server, so I need to choose the right host depending on whether or not it's a prod build.

I started off with `#ifdef DEBUG` to toggle between `http://localhost` and `https://proddomain.com`, but obviously `localhost` resolves correctly only on the simulator and not on the iphone.

I was hoping there'd be some scheme where you do port forwarding, etc to get it to work the same between simulator and test device. I'm currently hardcoding my local IP in the DEBUG build, and that won't work once more people are working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like registering a URL handler then using that to configure the app. It can be as simple as typing your custom URL into mobile Safari.

See [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) and [this step-by-step guide](http://appurl.org/docs/ios).

e.g. if you type myapp://config?endpoint=192.168.0.123:8080 (correctly quoted, of course),
your app will be launched and you can extract the endpoint, overriding your production version.

Comment: Do URL handlers affect outbound connections using NSURLConnection? I'm not sure this addresses making connections to the right host.

Comment: No, it doesn't affect NSURL connection, see my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found anything better, so grudgingly accepting this as the answer. :P Thanks for your help.

Comment: or you could use a proxy, like Charles. You set the iPhone wifi proxy to be your mac and let charls rewrite the URLs